Existence of a distribution for specific moments and support.
Suppose we are given a set of moments of some random variable $X$ with bouned support $[a,b]$ where $a,b>0$.
The moments are $\{M_i(X)\}_{i=1}^n$ where $M_i=\mathbb{E}[X^i]$.
Are there conditions on this set of moments which are suffecient for such a random variable to exist. It is clearly necassary that for any polynomial which is positive in $[a,b]$ we can find a weighted sum of moments which must be positive. So if we have $k$ moments this needs to be checked for all polynomials degree less than $k-1$.
However, I am unable to prove that this conditioon is also suffecient.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem
